# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: ytplayer

Tags: youtube

I'm trying to make a site that includes embedded Youtube videos.
From out of the blue, seemingly, the console in Chrome inspector began showing the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: ytplayer

It does not seem to really affect anything.

I then created a completely blank document, embedded a fresh video onto it and recieved the same error.
It even appears on Youtube itself, for me.
Does anyone have any idea on what this is?

Comment: I'm seeing the same error in my youtube module. It didn't have this error last week, so I'm guessing it's on YT's end.

Comment: Since this started happening, videos are no longer showing up in IE8. Anyone else experience this?

Comment: Yep, I've just come across exactly the same. The errors don't occur on Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

Fist check that javacript is enabled in your browser.And even check flash too.
Settings -> privacy -> content settings.
After that ,problem occurs again ,then reset your settings in browser
settings->reset settings.
because sometimes changing settings lead to this kind of problems.
even now problem occurs again ,then
I think the problem was your browser.
use alternate browser for good results.